# Typo3 Extension: Controllers can't be found by Backend Module

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-extensions

Recently I've been trying to create a Backend Module for my extension. More or less for self study reasons, since I technically don't need it, but still, it'd be nice to know what i'm doing wrong.

Basically: I have an extension, that works perfectly fine. I can create records in the Backend and the Frontend Actions also work as the should, but for some reason my Backend Module can't find the assigned controllers, even though they work in the Frontend.

"Could not analyse class: `Vendor\Icingaconfgen\Controller\ApplianceController` maybe not loaded or no autoloader? Class `Vendor\Icingaconfgen\Controller\ApplianceController` does not exist"

That's how i registered my Backend Module in the **ext_tables.php**:

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
        'Vendor.'.$_EXTKEY,
        'web',          // Main area
        'mod1',         // Name of the module
        '',             // Position of the module
        array(          // Allowed controller action combinations
                'Appliance' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
                'Host' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete'

        ),
        array(          // Additional configuration
            'access'    => 'user,group',
            'labels'    => 'LLL:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_mod.xml',
        )
    );
}
```

Maybe there is a missunderstanding on my side. So these controllers are the same as those i use in the Frontend!?

Comment: Go to Install tool : 1) Flush system cache, 2) dump auto-load (if t3v 8.x) 3) trash typo3temp files. This all because your namespace could not registered properly

Comment: Didn't work... I'm on 7.6 btw.

Comment: OK, problem solved... It was because i did a mistake while registering the Backend Module. (wrong Vendor name)

Comment: Please answer your question yourself to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the correct vendor name given in. It may be is case-sensitive

```
registerModule(
        'Vendor.' . $_EXTKEY,
        'web',          // Main area
        'mod1',         // Name of the module
        '',             // Position of the module
        array(          // Allowed controller action combinations
            'Name' => 'list'
            ),
        array(          // Additional configuration
            'access'    => 'user,group',
            'labels'    => 'LLL:EXT:'.$_EXTKEY.'/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_mod.xml',
        )
    );
```